# Javascript Case Change inputted text to something else

Tags: javascript, case

I have a problem with this one, and I know very very little JS

The Code below, I want to be able to enter abcd for example in a form click submit and it gives me another output which is defined below. This works fine as long as it's just ONE character, see below case 5 works, i type in 5 and it gives me Hodor 5, if i type in 55 it gives me the value "55" not Hodor 55.

Any ideas?

```
function toAlpha(form) {
    var myText = form.text.value;
    var newText = "";
    var curChar;
    for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; ++i) {
        curChar = myText.charAt(i);
        switch (curChar) {
        case '5':
            newText = "Hodor 5";
            break;
        case '55':
            newText = "Hodor 55";
            break;
        case '555':
            newText = "Hodor 555";
            break;
        default:
            newText += curChar;
            break;
        }
    }
    form.alpha.value = newText;
}
```

Comment: You're iterating over each character in the value, and yet you're checking for 55, but as you're iterating and using charAt you only have one character, not two, so it makes no sense to check for 55. Remove the iteration and check the value directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the value of input field, then what is the use of the loop? Try this:-

```
   function toAlpha(form){
   var myText = form.text.value;
   var newText = "";
    switch (myText) {
    case '5': newText = "Hodor 5";
     break;
    case '55': newText = "Hodor 55";
     break;
    case '555': newText = "Hodor 555";
     break;
    default:
     newText += myText;
     break;

   }
 form.alpha.value = newText;

 }
```